# GCC store all strings in .rodata

Tags: c, gcc, kernel, x86-64, elf

In my x86-64 kernel, I am trying to map the `.rodata` ELF section as readonly. But all the string literals, are stored in a file-specific section, e.g. `.rodata.str1.8`. Are there any option for GCC to store all strings in `.rodata` instead, or can I concatenate the `.rodata.str.x` into `.rodata` using `ld`, `objdump` or anything else?

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
  . = 0xC0100000;
  kernel_memory_start = .;
  .boot ALIGN(8) :
  {
  *(.multiboot)
  }

  .text ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000)
  {
  kernel_text_start = .;
    *(.text)
  }
  kernel_text_end = .;
  .rodata ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.rodata) - 0xC0000000)
  {
    kernel_rodata_start = .;
  *(.rodata)
  }
  kernel_rodata_end = .;

  .data ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.data) - 0xC0000000)
  {
  kernel_data_start = .;
    *(.data)
  }
  kernel_data_end = .;

  .bss ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.bss) - 0xC0000000)
  {
  kernel_bss_start = .;
    *(.bss)
  }
  kernel_bss_end = .;
  kernel_memory_end = .;
}
```

Compiler flags:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -mcmodel=large -fno-pic -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-3dnow -mno-80387 -fno-unwind-tables ...
```

Linker flags:

```
ld -nostdlib -n ...
```

Comment: Isn't this what your linker script ought to do?!

Comment: [I.e.](http://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts#SECTIONS)

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a proper [mcve] explaining what it is that you're doing now

Comment: Usually this is done for COMDAT resolution. In simple it is to avoid creation of duplicate strings. But post linking it should all be combined into a single section. Atleast you can tell your linker to do so

Comment: This may seem a bit off the beaten path, but I am curious if this is on MacOS?

Comment: No, I am using Linux with the ELF linker `x86_64-elf-ld`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your linker file, use *(.rodata*)